# Why can't I remove 2 items in a row using an Iterator?

Tags: java, iterator

I use an `Iterator` to iterate over a list of items. Based on the value of the element, I need to delete the current and the following items. 
However, when deleting multiple items in a row, I get an exception `IllegalStateException`

Code example:

```
Iterator<String> it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
       String elem = it.next();

       if (elem != null && ...)
           it.remove();

       // condition #2
       else if (elem != null && ...) {
           it.remove();
           if (it.hasNext())
               it.remove();
       }
}
```

If condition #2 is met, I get an error when deleting elements. 
Could you explain this behavior? Thanks!

Comment: Condition #2 tries to remove the same element twice. If you need to remove the element after it you need to advance the iterator over the next element.

Comment: Explaination of behavior: Javadoc of [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) says: *Removes from the underlying collection the **last element returned** by this iterator (optional operation). This method can be called only **once per call to `next()`**.* --- Your code is calling `remove()` twice, without calling `next()` again in-between.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get an error the second time you call method `it.remove()` in condition #2.
The reason lies in the principle of the Java Iterator's, which need to be perceived as if their positions are between the elements.
When you call method `next()`, the iterator jumps to the next element and returns a reference to the element that it just passed.

The `Iterator` interface method `remove()` - deletes the element that was returned by the last `next()` call.
In many situations, this makes sense - you need to see the item before you decide that it needs to be deleted. **But if you want to delete an element located in a certain position, you will have to go through it.**

The `Iterator` doesn't seem to be the best way to go through the list for your case. It’s easier to use the list you have and the loop inside which will be your logic for deleting elements.
However, if you still need to use the Iterator, you need to fix the second condition as follows:

```
       // condition #2
       if (elem != null && ...) {
           it.remove();
           if (it.hasNext()) {
               it.next();
               it.remove();
           }
       }
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: glad I helped :)

Answer (score 2):

Once you've called `remove` the first time, you need to call `next` to advance to the next entry before removing it (just `hasNext` isn't sufficient). So:

```
it.remove();
if (it.hasNext()) {
    it.next();
    it.remove();
}
```